# What MongoDb/Mongoose method shoud I pick?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

based on the image I added, how can I make the updated Documents to be saved and reflect it on the database?

btw I'm using mongoDb

[image]

and the scenario is like when I checkout the products on the middle image, it should be deducted from the `current document`'s image and then the result will be saved on the database

i've tried using `Model.updateMany()` but it doesn't work on my end (*or rather there is something I missed?*)

Hoping you can help me to solve my problem

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Tell me full updateMany query

Comment: this one? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiZsdHS1_z9AhXdAjQIHTmuCUoQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-ask&usg=AOvVaw00xttYhbqoB7L7CXC05R8r). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: I see, sorry my bad, didn't think of it :(

Answer (score 0):

mongoose [`Model.bulkWrite()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) can update multiple documents in one collection with different conditions and data:

> Sends multiple `insertOne`, `updateOne`, `updateMany`, `replaceOne`, `deleteOne`, and/or `deleteMany` operations to the MongoDB server in one command.

E.g.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { config } from '../../src/config';

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  stocks: Number,
})
const Product = mongoose.model('product', productSchema);

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  productId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product' },
  productName: String,
  quantity: Number
});
const Order = mongoose.model('order', orderSchema);

(async function main() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });
    const createdProducts = await Product.create([{ name: 'item1', stocks: 10 }, { name: 'item2', stocks: 10 }, { name: 'item3', stocks: 10 }])
    const createdOrders = await Order.create([
      { productId: createdProducts[0]._id, productName: createdProducts[0].name, quantity: 1 },
      { productId: createdProducts[1]._id, productName: createdProducts[1].name, quantity: 2 },
      { productId: createdProducts[2]._id, productName: createdProducts[2].name, quantity: 3 }
    ])

    console.log('createdProducts: ', createdProducts)
    console.log('createdOrders: ', createdOrders)

    const ops = createdOrders.map((order) => {
      return {
        updateOne: {
          filter: {
            _id: order.productId,
          },
          update: { $inc: { stocks: -order.quantity } },
        },
      };
    });
    await Product.bulkWrite(ops);

    const updatedProducts = await Product.find();
    console.log('updatedProducts: ', updatedProducts)

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    await Promise.all(['products', 'orders'].map(co => mongoose.connection.dropCollection(co)))
    await mongoose.connection.close()
  }
})();
```

Logs:

```bash
createdProducts:  [
  { _id: 6464c5d9ec0dd0b5da83acaf, name: 'item1', stocks: 10, __v: 0 },
  { _id: 6464c5d9ec0dd0b5da83acb0, name: 'item2', stocks: 10, __v: 0 },
  { _id: 6464c5d9ec0dd0b5da83acb1, name: 'item3', stocks: 10, __v: 0 }
]
createdOrders:  [
  {
    _id: 6464c5daec0dd0b5da83acb5,
    productId: 6464c5d9ec0dd0b5da83acaf,
    productName: 'item1',
    quantity: 1,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 6464c5daec0dd0b5da83acb6,
    productId: 6464c5d9ec0dd0b5da83acb0,
    productName: 'item2',
    quantity: 2,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 6464c5daec0dd0b5da83acb7,
    productId: 6464c5d9ec0dd0b5da83acb1,
    productName: 'item3',
    quantity: 3,
    __v: 0
  }
]
updatedProducts:  [
  { _id: 6464c5d9ec0dd0b5da83acaf, name: 'item1', stocks: 9, __v: 0 },
  { _id: 6464c5d9ec0dd0b5da83acb0, name: 'item2', stocks: 8, __v: 0 },
  { _id: 6464c5d9ec0dd0b5da83acb1, name: 'item3', stocks: 7, __v: 0 }
]
```

As you can see, we updated the value of the `stocks` field in `createdProducts` documents with `createOrders` documents when the `order.productId` matched `product._id`.